# How to select an item in dropdown of multiple menus where each menu contains the same ID, class, and Xpath in python

Tags: python, selenium

[there have only add row. this is when I click 3 times in add row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBqJI.jpg)I have to add 3 rows or menus and select one item from the dropdown of each row or menu. This code adds 3 rows but selects items from the 1st row in every time Because of the same ID, class, and Xpath. How can I select items in each row?

```
                <input class="button add-repeater-specialities" type="button" id="am_specialities" value="Add row">
            <select name="am_specialities[309277][speciality_id]" id="specialities-dp" class="item-specialities-dp chosen-select">
                <option value="0">Select Speciality</option>
                <option class="level-0" value="1056">cancer</option>
                <option class="level-0" value="1064">orthopedics </option>
                <option class="level-0" value="1075">Azma</option>
                
            </select>
            <input class="button add-repeater-specialities" type="button" id="am_specialities" value="Add row">
            <select name="am_specialities[341276][speciality_id]" id="specialities-dp" class="item-specialities-dp chosen-select">
                <option value="0">Select Speciality</option>
                <option class="level-0" value="1056">cancer</option>
                <option class="level-0" value="1064">orthopedics </option>
                <option class="level-0" value="1075">Azma</option>
            </select>

            <input class="button add-repeater-specialities" type="button" id="am_specialities" value="Add row">
            <select name="am_specialities[341276][speciality_id]" id="specialities-dp" class="item-specialities-dp chosen-select">
                <option value="0">Select Speciality</option>
                <option class="level-0" value="1056">cancer</option>
                <option class="level-0" value="1064">orthopedics </option>
                <option class="level-0" value="1075">Azma</option>
            </select>

            from selenium import webdriver
            from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

            #To add 1st row
            search_specialities1 = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="am_specialities"]').click()
            #To select dropdown item of  1st row
            select = Select(browser.find_element(By.ID,'specialities-dp'))
            select.select_by_value('53')
            #To add 2nd row
            search_specialities2 = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="am_specialities"]').click()
            #To select dropdown item of  2nd row
            select = Select(browser.find_element(By.ID,'specialities-dp'))
            select.select_by_value('54')
            #To add 3rd row
            search_specialities3 = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="am_specialities"]').click()
            #To select dropdown item of  3rd row
            select = Select(browser.find_element(By.ID,'specialities-dp'))
            select.select_by_value('73')
```

Answer (score 0):

The first row always gets selected because the xpath matches multiple elements and keeps the first one only. You can use find_elements instead which returns a list of all matching elements and then iterate through each one of them.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

values = ['53', '54', '73']

speciality = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="am_specialities"]')
speciality.click()

for index in range(len(values)):
    select = Select(speciality.find_element_by_xpath('./select[@id="specialities-dp"]'))
    select.select_by_value(values[index])
    search_specialities = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//input[@id="am_specialities"]')
    speciality = search_specialities[index+1]
    speciality.click()
```

Comment: ZhorGen Thanks. Almost near. But elements in ""search_specialities = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//input[@id="am_specialities"]') """" not work because there are only one row (<input class="button add-repeater-specialities" type="button" id="am_specialities" value="Add row">) before execute codes.
the process is that at first, you have to click on #<input# to create a  new row and dropdown option # <select>#. Then click again on #<input# to create another new row and dropdown option # <select>#.I can not select #<select# because of the same XPath, id and name. i.stack.imgur.com/TBqJI.jpg

Comment: Oh so the inputs don't exist at first there's only one. Okay I see now the picture. What I can suggest is to click on the one input available select the value you want then search for the new created. I will edit my answer for you.